# Problems with circular reference

Tags: c++

Say we have a class named `TestAPI` and a class named `UserAPI`. An object of the class `UserAPI` is created and included in the header of class `TestAPI`.

Now, an instance of object `UserAPI` must have access to private member variables of an instance of `TestAPI` but this doesn't work because there is no specific object created. I want the users of my library to create an object in their code (`TestAPI`) so this object is created later on.

Example:

```
main.cpp
{
    TestAPI test;
    test.User.SomeExampleToChangeRequest(); 
}

class TestAPI
{
    friend class UserAPI;
    public:
        UserAPI User;

    private:
        HINTERNET _hRequest;    // Variable which needs to be accessed from User    
};
```

Now a method from class UserAPI to change the request handle

```
UserAPI::SomeExampleToChangeRequest ()
{
    // how do I access _hRequest now? 
    // TestAPI._hRequest will not work since it's not static and class "global"
}
```

How do I perform this? Defining this as friend works only for the access permission and does not solve my problem.

Comment: IMO it would be easier to understand if you just write a few lines of example code, rather than trying to explain what you want to do.

Comment: yep, added the situation where I got stuck. Hopefully it is easier to understand now.

Comment: What is the connection between TestAPI and UserAPI? How should they interact? If a UserAPI instance needs access to a TestAPI object then you have to give it one.

Comment: yep but that would end up in a synchronization and I don't think that this is a good way.

Comment: What do you mean by synchronization? Maybe you can explain the general problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: already explained that above. I want to update the post statistics and I don't want to put these update method in the TestAPI class because it'll fit better in the user class (since statistics are for users). so the problem is the access, objects are created in the main and those cannot be accessed by my user object in the TestAPI class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the clearer way to explain why this isn't possible out of the box is that each instance of UserAPI has no idea where it was created or what it is for.

Honestly with such a direct linkage here you might need to provide UserAPI with some kind of "parent" TestAPI pointer/reference when it is constructed to allow it to call the _hRequest method.

EDIT:

Basically change your definition of UserAPI to this below:

```
// Forward declaration
class TestAPI;

class UserAPI
{
public:

    UserAPI( TestAPI* inParent )
    : m_parent ( inParent )
    {}

private:

    // Let's make this private to force construction with a TestAPI parent
    UserAPI(){}

    TestAPI* m_parent;
};
```

Note the forward declaration, as the compiler needs to know this exists.
If you're using header files then put this declaration at the top of your userAPI.h and only include the testAPI.h in userAPI.cpp.

Bear in mind this won't allow you to call any TestAPI functions from within the userAPI.h, but it will give full access within userAPI.cpp

As a result of that `UserAPI::SomeExampleToChangeRequest` will need to be defined in userAPI.cpp

```
UserAPI::SomeExampleToChangeRequest ()
{
    // The TestAPI variable or function can now be accessed like so
    m_parent->_hRequest;
}
```

Quick last note: if you're not wanting to use separate header and cpp files then as long as you define `UserAPI::SomeExampleToChangeRequest` after the definition of TestAPI then you'll be good to go.

Final note: as mentioned by Happy the friend isn't really needed and should be used sparingly in object oriented C++. It would be preferable to make a public function to access that parameter

Comment: Could you edit some code fragment how to provide that as a pointer?

Comment: Thanks, now I can access the variable but they don't contain anything. :/

Answer (score 1):

There are two main improvement areas in your understanding of object oriented design with C++.

- Your first choice to provide access to a private member should be a public method, not `friend`.
- To access an object of another type in a method, you should pass an object of that type. Do not start thinking of static or global objects, unless that is what you really want.

I have posted some code snippets below. Put them together to solve your problem.

```
class TestAPI {
public:
    // method to modify _hRequest
    void set_hRequest(HINTERNET& in_hRequest) {
        _hRequest = in_hRequest;
    }

    // method to access _hRequest
    HINTERNET& get_hRequest() {
        return _hRequest;
    }

private:
    HINTERNET _hRequest;
};
```

.

```
UserAPI::SomeExampleToChangeRequest(TestAPI& t) {
    // use 't' to access TestAPI here, like so ...
    HINTERNET h = t.get_hRequest();  
}
```

Once your user creates the `TestAPI` object, have them pass it by reference to the `UserAPI::SomeExampleToChangeRequest()` method. Additionally, use a forward declaration as mentioned by gbjbaanb, to aid the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [forward declaration](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/), which is a way to say "this definition will be provided later" so your code will syntax check correctly, and the compiler will sort things out for you later (which it knows the full definitions for both classes).

However, there are limitations. Because the compiler doesn't know anything about the forwardly-declared class, you can't refer to its methods, or its size. This means you pretty much have to refer to it via a pointer, which you hopefully wrap in a smart pointer.